# How to change a text in a word document by using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, text-alignment, direction

I have created a program in Excel VBA, this program copy from Word document content and paste it to the mail body. But I have tried to change the direction of one text in the document and used `.ParagraphFormat.Alignment` but it didn't work.

I tried this code

```
Sub sendMail()


    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim olm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim Cell As Range



    For r = 23 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row

        With wd.Selection.Find
        
            .Text = "<<Duration>>"
            .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 32).Value
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
        End With
        
        
        With wd.Selection.Find
        
            .Text = "<<objectivs>>"
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft   'this code suppose to change the direction but it didn't work
            .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 33).Value
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            
        End With


    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: If you post the whole sub code in OP, you missed `Set wd = GetObject(, "word.application")`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.Replacement.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
```

Comment: @Dominique how is this not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for a paragraph with the required alignment, not setting it. The use of Selection is also very inefficient. Try:

```
For r = 23 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row
  With wd.ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .Text = "<<Duration>>"
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 32).Value
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "<<objectivs>>"
    .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 33).Value
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next
```

Note that, unless you want all except the first <<Duration>> paragraph's format changed, you need to ensure it is cleared for each iteration.

Comment: I tried to write this code and the text was in left but  it didn't affect on the direction of the text. what i need is to change the direction of the text

Comment: Well, the code you posted, is for affecting the paragraph alignment, not the text direction, so that's what I took it that you were trying to achieve. I'm not a mind reader. If you want to change the *direction*, use .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.ReadingOrder = wdReadingOrderLtr instead of .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it is supposed to be like this:

`.Replacement.ParagraphFormat.ReadingOrder = wdReadingOrderLtr`